# npm e2e testing, doesn't work in github actions in the pipeline but works fine locally : Error - Process completed with exit code 1

Tags: npm, github-actions, e2e-testing

So i've got the ci: lint test, unit test, sast and packaging to work fine. But the e2e testing doesn't work properly on GitHub actoins. I am running it solely by itself to see if it works, but it keeps coming up with this error.

- Process completed with exit code 1.

I've run these commands in order to run on terminal. Get docker to get the container up and get the server started etc etc. So that the e2e can work.

- npx playwright install
- docker-compose up -d
- npm run start
- npm run test-e2e

[this is the e2e code that i have in my yml.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nxep3.png)

Comment: Hi @jackson, please provide a minimal sample that reproduces your problem. Pasting links or images means future people with the same problem can't find your question. Here are some hints on how to ask a good question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask